# I want both .RedirectStandardOutput = true/false

Tags: redirectstandardoutput

//by this code i want the batch file which is going to be executed will show the output on shell screen which i got by **RedirectStandardOutput = false;**

but i also want at that same time output should be redirected to a log file for this i have to do this as **RedirectStandardOutput = true;**

but once one can be used either **true** or **false** please help me great programers ... !!

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\test\build.bat";

        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;


        p.Start();

        string output = null;
      //  try
      //  {

            output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

      //  }
      //  catch (Exception ex)
      //  {
      //     MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
      //  }

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("c:\test\log.txt", output);
```

Comment: Which language is this? C#? Please tag it with appropriate language tags.

Comment: Don't flag your post because you need help.  Its an abuse of the moderation system.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the output that you received from `p.StandardOutput` to `Console.Write`.
To see the output appear in real time, replace the single `ReadToEnd` call with a looped call to `ReadLine`.

Comment: but this is my windows form application how can i use console.write
i got an output when i am using  p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false; but if i use "false" i am unable to redirect the output in a log file... i want both plz give me solution :(